# What does scale and step values in .cfg file of YOLO means?

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to understand the .cfg file of YOLOv2. I didn't understand

steps=-1,100,80000,100000

scales=.1,10,.1,.1

Can someone explain me this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`steps` is a checkpoints (number of iterations) at which scales will be applied.

`scales` is a coefficients at which `learning_rate` will be multiplied at this checkpoints. Determines how the `learning_rate` will be changed during increasing number of iterations during training.

Both of them are related to each other and they have the same amount.

```
steps=200,400,600,20000,30000

scales=2.5,2,2,.1,.1
```

At step 200 the scales is 2.5, step 400 the scale is 2, etc.

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/279