# Step size in YOLOv4 Model

Tags: deep-learning, config, object-detection, yolo

So I was reading this [guide](https://medium.com/@toprashantshekhar/yolov4-custom-object-detector-with-darknet-in-colab-notebook-facemask-detection-2621f7f54dfe) about object detector training. It is instructed to change **step size** to 80% and 90% of the maximum batch size. Can someone explain what this step size is? And how it impacts the training. And also why specifically 80 and 90 percent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step mentioned in the guide determines  the number of iterations at which scales will be applied. Check [What does scale and step values in .cfg file of YOLO means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372310/what-does-scale-and-step-values-in-cfg-file-of-yolo-means)

Try not to call it step size, since the step size is something completely different from the step.

The step size is the learning rate, is a hyperparameter that defines how quickly the model adapts to the problem, learn more about [learning Rate](https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-rate-for-deep-learning-neural-networks/#:%7E:text=The%20amount%20that%20the%20weights,range%20between%200.0%20and%201.0.) and [its impact on training](https://machinelearningmastery.com/understand-the-dynamics-of-learning-rate-on-deep-learning-neural-networks/) on the cited links.